# Virtuemart modal box not working

Tags: joomla-2.5, virtuemart

I have Virtuemart 2.0.26D in my website; when I go to the product details page of a product, if I click in the image of that product, the pop-up that should appear, doesn't.

The image that I have clicked appears in a new window...

Any idea about how to solve this?

Comment: Sounds like javascript issues. Check your browser's console for errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your **Virtuemart** -> **Configuration** -> **Templates tab** and locate the following setting:

[image: VirtueMart Template settings]

Then change the setting of "Use Fancybox". If it is checked, try unchecking it, and vice verse.

VirtueMart includes two systems for product display - Fancybox and Facebox. Fancybox is more advanced, but will in some cases cause javascript conflicts with some templates and/or extensions.

To see if there's any conflict, press <kbd>F12</kbd> in your browser to load the developer tools. You should be able to see any Javascript conflicts in the console.

Comment: It doesn't work... I checked the console and I found these errors http://gyazo.com/865d3e926a0b726c42488e6c80c790c5. Also, I have to say that when I'm in the 'modal box', I can't even log in...

Comment: You have to make sure jQuery is loaded before any jQuery plugins, and only once. Check you source code by pressing **Ctrl+U**. The error message **Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined** has a solution [here](https://github.com/parsimony/parsimony/issues/45) that you could try. What do you mean with *when in 'modal box' I can't even log in*?